# Rengwuxian Material EditText library hint not showing

Tags: android

for some reason andriod is not showing text view hint or any hint at all and not only that but also when putting in text to show what text view is, its not showing what text view is at all. Like box one text view, am trying to add text into the box as email but its not showing....this is so frustrating...spending 3-4 hours and i can't figure this out...I heard this was andriod bug or something? anyone got a clue? I tried stack overflow on text view hint not showing and its not helping me at all..so here is the xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_Layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF9800"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lb_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="MyBlog"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lb_SubTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="My Persional Blog"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lb_title" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:background="#AFB42B"
        android:foreground="@color/white"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFEB3B"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lb_SubTitle" >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/innerLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:ellipsize="start"
                android:hint="@string/HintEmail"
                android:text="@string/HintEmail"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:met_baseColor="#0056d3"
                app:met_errorColor="#ddaa00"
                app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
                app:met_floatingLabelText="Email"
                app:met_primaryColor="#982360"
                tools:text="email" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: you need to use either `android:hint` or `android:met_floatingLabelText`, you will face issue in it...

Comment: not working still..

Answer (score 0):

Make your code as follows to show hint in materialedittext

```
  <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:text="@string/HintEmail"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:met_baseColor="#0056d3"
            app:met_errorColor="#ddaa00"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
            app:met_floatingLabelText="Email"
            app:met_primaryColor="#982360" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this attribute `tools:text="email"`

try this:

```
  <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:hint="@string/HintEmail"
            android:text="@string/HintEmail"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:met_baseColor="#0056d3"
            app:met_errorColor="#ddaa00"
            app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
            app:met_floatingLabelText="Email"
            app:met_primaryColor="#982360" />
```

Comment: Remove original `hint` attribute
            `android:hint="@string/HintEmail"`

Comment: i made a new app and its working fine now. not sure what happen.